# Adaptive Lasso and Multicollinearity

Tags: feature-selection, lasso, multicollinearity

I have been reading through several sources trying to determine the ability of different methods in the presence of multicollinearity. I understand that OLS regression and the lasso do not perform well when variables in the design matrix are collinear, and I understand that ridge regression and elastic net are often used to remedy the problem. However, I am still unclear about the adaptive lasso and the effect of collinearity between variables.

I came across [the Random Lasso paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.3398.pdf) which states that it does not perform as well as the lasso if using the OLS weights. Which is fine, [Zou recommends using ridge regression weights](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Ezouxx019/Papers/adalasso.pdf) when you suspect collinearity to be present in the data. My question is, does the adaptive lasso itself perform well with multicollinearity in the data? Assuming we use ridge weights and the oracle property exists, is it an acceptable model to use?

Thanks.